# Why does `ls -d *[!e]*` display all files instead of omitting all files that contain an e?

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards

`ls -d *e*` prints out all files containing an "e" somewhere in it. But the opposite, `ls -d *[!e]*` does not seem to work. Why exactly is that?

is it because `ls` takes `*` as its own argument and expands all the files?

I understand I can do: `ls -d !(*e*)` (in Bash with `extglob` set, or in ksh).

Comment: All files that contain a character that is not an e?

Comment: @frostschutz  yes

Comment: i would highly recommend learning to use find and regexps for anything beyond the most basic file matching purposes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What that glob is actually doing is matching any number of characters, then a single character other than an e, then any number of characters. It will match any file with a name that isn't composed entirely of e's.